# The proper name of just subtracting the mean?

Tags: mean, terminology, normalization

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)

Normalization is subtracting the mean then dividing by the standard deviation. What is the name of just subtracting the mean?

Comment: Mean centering, I'd say.

Comment: Sometimes also called de-meaned variables.

Comment: Just _subtracting the mean_ is good enough in my view, and no other term is essential. (I would contest the definition of normalization if only because the same word is also used in other senses, as indeed your link does emphasise.)

Comment: Concurrent thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572280/de-meaning-or-differencing-the-mean-of-in-mathematical-term

Comment: It is a matter of preference. Personally, I don't like "de-meaned" as it suggests that it removed the mean. That is misleading because subtracting the mean just means the transformed variable has a mean of zero, and zero is not nothing! :P It also creates a phonetic map collision with the term ["demean"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demean).

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments: I agree with COOLSerdash that *mean centering* is the best term for this. Nick Cox is right that *subtracting the mean* clearly explains things, but the former is used more commonly in other grammatical forms. E.g. *mean-centered data* is a more commonly used term than *mean-subtracted data*.

I personally don't like *de-meaning* because it's too close in spelling and pronunciation to the existing (and completely different) word 'demeaning'.